# RF Transmitter and receiver circuits

Tags: rf, transmitter, receiver

I need to build a RF transmitter and receiver circuit for a class project. Size and scaleability is important. I would like it to be as close to hand held as possible for both ends. 9V power source. I'm working on it myself but I haven't aquired enough training yet to be able to do this myself. I can read schematics well but not good enough yet for design. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Try looking up radio modules on google. Also type-in the operating frequency (such as 433 MHz in europe or 315 MHz for other places). Find out what ISM bands are valid for your country. What you want to transmit may not be allowed but this is usually all about how low your transmit power output is. Link to pretty pictures: https://www.google.com/search?q=433+MHz+radio+module&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV8_yP8eTPAhWL0RoKHSZRB50Q_AUICSgC&biw=1204&bih=893

Comment: Can you tell us anything about what kind of information you're trying to transmit? Is it analog or digital? Bandwidth? What kind of distance do you expect it to cover? How reliable does it need to be, and how much latency can you tolerate? As it stands, this question is far too broad.

Comment: In the United States, check the *ARRL Handbook* (arrl.org) as a resource for amateur radio circuit designs.

Answer (score 0):

If the class project is actually designing and building a transmitter and receiver, then there are hundreds of example circuits on the internet for reference and inspiration. In particular, study the examples that show photographs of the physical construction. It would have been helpful to mention WHAT you are trying to transmit?  Speech?  Data?  Video?

If the wireless link is only a component of a larger project, then there are many modular transmitters and receivers available for audio, video, and data. Many of them sell for much less than the individual components cost, not to mention that they are assembled and tested.

Note that designing RF circuits is rather tricky to get everything right. Physical layout and construction is critical in many circuits.  It probably isn't an ideal project for someone with little or no experience. Even people with years of experience building circuits from scratch avoid RF circuits because they are particularly difficult. Especially without good test equipment (like an oscilloscope, etc.).